# How to fix unresolved identifier 'stopRunning' error for AVcapture session

Tags: ios, swift

I am building a barcode scanner on iOS using swift. This worked perfectly when I first wrote the code but I recently returned to the programming and dicovered that it's throwing some errors.
I have an exit scan button when the user press the button, it should exit the scanning mode

this is the exitScan button

```
  let exitScanButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 80, g: 101, b: 161)
    button.setTitle("Exit", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
   button.addTarget( nil, action: #selector(exitScan), for:.touchUpInside)
    return button
}()
```

this is my exitScan function

```
   func exitScan() -> Void {
    //Go back to ViewController
    [self.captureSession, stopRunning];
    [self.videoPreviewLayer, removeFromSuperlayer];
    self.videoPreviewLayer = nil;
    self.captureSession = nil;
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Xcode is throwing two errors

> Use of unresolved identifier 'stopRunning'
>
> Use of unresolved identifier 'removeFromSuperlayer'

How is this an error and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's objective-c syntax.

In Swift:

`self.catpureSession.stopRunning()`

`self.videoPreviewLayer.removeFromSuperLayer()`

no semicolons also.